# How to compare two mysql row ids and extract stores which is not including

Tags: mysql

[image: Table Structure]

As you can see in the table above, we have two `culture`s, with `cultureid`s of `4` and `5`.

Each culture has some stores which are the same, and some have which are different, i.e. `cultureid` 4 has some stores that `cultureid` 5 does not.

How we can extract the stores which are not same in both `culture`s?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You question is fuzzy! Please just give the structure of the different tables, a sample and expected data, and may be the query you've tried. This way we can easily help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first thing first, I think you should add your schema of the tables so we can provide you with better answers. More over the screenshot of the Query and the result beneath differ so we it is not very easy to understand the exact structure of your data. And you have an error in the Query - `**c.**cultureid = **c.**cultureid`, I think it should be *s.cultureid = c.cultureid*.

But any way, if we consider your **nl_stores** table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nl_stores` (
  cultureid INT(10) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Meaning you have the **cultureid** and **name** fields in it, then you can use this query to find the results you are looking for, using the HAVING method:

```
SELECT cultureid, name FROM nl_stores GROUP BY name HAVING(COUNT(cultureid) = 1);
```

Another way to do it would be using the EXISTS statmant:

```
SELECT nl_stores.cultureid, nl_stores.name FROM nl_stores WHERE !EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM nl_stores AS nl_stores_dummy WHERE nl_stores_dummy.name = nl_stores.name AND nl_stores_dummy.cultureid != nl_stores.cultureid);
```

And of course you can also achieve it using a JOIN:

```
SELECT nl_stores.cultureid, nl_stores.name FROM nl_stores LEFT JOIN nl_stores AS nl_stores_dummy ON nl_stores_dummy.name = nl_stores.name WHERE nl_stores_dummy.cultureid IS NULL;
```

Here is a full example based on the data you provided I consider the following DB structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nl_cultures` (
  cultureid INT(10) NOT NULL,
  culture_name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `nl_cultures` (`cultureid`, `culture_name`) VALUES
  ('4', 'Culture 1'),
  ('5', 'Culture 2');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nl_stores` (
  cultureid INT(10) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the Query could be:

```
SELECT nl_cultures.culture_name, nl_stores.name AS store_name 
FROM nl_cultures
INNER JOIN nl_stores ON nl_stores.cultureid = nl_cultures.cultureid
WHERE nl_stores.status = 1
GROUP BY nl_stores.name 
HAVING(COUNT(nl_stores.cultureid) = 1);
```

Usually the JOIN statement would be the fastest executed, but it depends on the amount of results you have in the table, based on that I would consider using the GROUP, which should be fast enough and works without any additional joins.

A couple of tips to *consider* which I learned in my experience:

- It would be best if you **do not** compare names, but IDs of those stores, it would be much, much, much faster also a lot better for indexing. If it is not the ID of the store, cause they are different in your different cultures, then consider providing them with some **numeric** key which identifies them and is the same no matter the culture.
- Also It is a lot easier to understand and follow up a query when you set understandable/readable table names and use them as references. For example: `store AS store_joined` instead of `store AS s`, because **s** is nothing and when you have a really long query with a couple of joins it could become difficult to distinguish all of them and really easy to skip any. Same goes for the column names, also it is better to separate column words with under underscore, `cultureid`, should be `culture_id`.
- One more is to consider **not** using special keywords like **status** as column names. If you are using some kind of DB tool it will be easier to track that.
- And one last thing, based on the query you have typed in the screenshot, use UPPER case letters for the sql keywords, easier to review the structure.

A nice tool to test your sql: http://sqlfiddle.com.

Hope I was helpful and if you have any question, please let me know and vote my answer if it worked for you :).

Comment: Hi svetoslav, Let me more specific...

For some countries we currently have 2 cultures. For example Belgium we have two cultures NL-BE and FR-BE.
We could add all NL-BE stores  in FR-BE and the other way around.
we want to see which stores have not been added on NL-BE.
Actually we want to compare two cultures which culture has same store, we want to get store which are not similar in both cultures. And which store is available in which culture.

Comment: Hi Atif,
Well, about working with cultures, you already have the tools and I've provided you with the sql queries.

Comment: You didn't suggested anything about countries in your initial request. But anyhow if you are working with cultures, you already have the tools and I've provided you the queries, so you can get stores which are not similar in cultures as per your initial request. With little modification you can get stores which have both cultures. And you have to build a select for collecting store and cultures, pretty simple.
I can help you with any of those, but they are totally different topics and as I said you need to provide much more info in order to be helpful, table schema, requests.

Comment: And one last thing, please accept/mark my answer if it helped with your initial problem. Thank you in advance.